# How to detect custom complexe objects?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, haar-classifier, yolo

I’m working on a program to detect the type of connectors and it should be able to add new models if we need to add a new type of connectors. or I could detect the port where the connectors should be plugged-in.

I tried the haar-classifier but i get false positives.
I don't have any problem with the python code because it shows me the results, so the main problem is in the training part.
The program detect these two connectors as if there are the same, my cascade is only trained to detect the brown one.

[image: picture1]
[image: picture 2]

Comment: show an example of your inputs and expected outputs as well as some example code. try to make a [MCVE]

Comment: thank you for your answer i added pictures to clarify the problem

Comment: For this objects it can use Features-based approach: SIFT, SURF etc

Comment: @Nuzhny I believe SURF performance won't beat deep learning trained model